# File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", No module name 'material' | AWS ec2 instance, django project

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-ec2, bootstrap-5

```
~/blog/blog$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/blog/blog/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/blog/blog/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'material'
```

when i tried to run this coomand makemigrations on aws ec2 for my django project, it appeared No module named 'material'

how can I fix this problems?

Comment: Did you add your "material" app to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: run this `pip install material`

Comment: yes, I added "material" to INSTALLED_APPS